# MPChangePlaybackPositionCommand is not work on ios 9.1

Tags: ios

MPChangePlaybackPositionCommand is a new api added by ios 9.1,but you can use it on ios8.0 -ios 9.1.you can use it to seek progress on lockScreen when play music.But,when i update my iphone to ios 9.1,it api can not work,anyone can tell me why?

Comment: In my case I witness similar issue on iOS 9.2

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I fond MPChangePlaybackPositionCommand has a private property - canBeControlledByScrubbing;This property default is NO.when you set YES to this property, you can seek progress in LockScreen in iOS 9

Comment: @Sunz how you are doing it? `[changePlaybackPositionCommand performSelector:@selector(setCanBeControlledByScrubbing:) withObject:shouldScrub];` doesnt work for me. Can you please show your code?